# What does cd "some path" >&- means?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I came across below code line in a shell script file.

```
cd "some path" >&-
```

Can anyone help to find the meaning of it ?

Comment: `man bash` search for Duplicating File Descriptors and Moving File Descriptors

Comment: Interestingly, the bash man page (at least in my version) does not seem to define the meaning of this construct, but AFIK, it means that stdout is closed for this command. You can try it out with `echo xxxx >&-`; bash will complain with an error message, because `echo` wants to write to stdout and this file descriptor is closed. However, `cd` doesn't write to stdout, and if it would, you would get an error message, so I don't quite see the reason for this construct either.

Comment: (Just FYI): **`cd` doesn't write to `stdout`** This is **NOT** true. try this: `cd ~; CDPATH=/; cd usr >&-` If `cd` goes through `CDPATH` paths the destination directory is written to `stdout`. This CDPATH mechanism is not commonly used one, but it's worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

*stdout* is closed. See [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (Duplicating File Descriptors). This doesn't make any sense in your example because `cd` doesn't write to *stdout* anyway.

Comment: Also, I would not suggest closing `stdout`/`stderr`. If the process tries to write to these file descriptors, (e.g. `ls >&-`) it would give you errors like `ls: write error: Bad file descriptor`. I would rather recommend redirecting these 2 FDs to `/dev/null`

Comment: **`cd` doesn't write to `stdout` anyway.** This is **NOT** true. try this: `cd ~; CDPATH=/; cd usr >&-` If `cd` goes through `CDPATH` paths then the destination directory is written to `stdout`. This CDPATH mechanism is not commonly used one, but it's worth noting.